# How to format text being written to a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have written a code that produces a receipt to a text file. At the moment the receipt is unformatted. It looks like this:

```
Order Form

GTIN     NAME        QUANTITY
11111115 , plain bracket , 12
22222220 , wheelbarrow , 238
```

I want to have the code in a neat format that looks similar to this:

```
Order Form

GTIN         NAME               QUANTITY
11111115     plain bracket      12
22222220     wheelbarrow        238
```

Is there a function in visual basic that will allow me to format how I write the text to the file? I have used `StringBuilder` to append the text (which is from a ListBox - resulting in it being in it's current format) to the text file, although I do not know if using `StringBuilder` over `StreamWriter` will make a difference in how I can format it.

Code I'm currently using:

```
Dim CreateReceipt As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
CreateReceipt.Append("Order Form")
CreateReceipt.Append(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
CreateReceipt.Append("GTIN" + "       " + "NAME" + "            " + "QUANTITY")
CreateReceipt.Append(Environment.NewLine)
For Each o As Object In lstOrderForm.Items
    CreateReceipt.AppendLine(o)
Next

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("order_receipt.txt", CreateReceipt.ToString())

Process.Start("order_receipt.txt")
```

Comment: Format text where you need to display it and use a file (or database) only as storage for the rawdata.

Comment: I am displaying it in a text file @TimSchmelter. One of the requirements of my project is that the data needs to be formatted neatly in a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.PadRight`. It will fill your string with blanks.

Example:

```
Dim x AS Integer = 0
Dim foo As String = x.ToString().PadRight(15)
'foo = "0              "
```

Comment: And of course the corresponding .PadLeft() for right-aligning a column. Keep in mind that the text file must be viewed with a monospace font (courier new for example) to produce neat columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming your `ListView` looks something like this:

[image]

My setup is 3 `Columns` and 3 `Items`. Each `Item` has 2 `SubItems`. This may differ to yours but should give you some idea.

I'm going to use the [String.PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx) method to evenly distribute the columns and text. I'm using **15** to pad however you really need to determine the longest string to ensure you pad correctly and evenly.

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine("Order Form" & vbCrLf)
sb.AppendLine("GTIN".PadRight(15) & "NAME".PadRight(15) & "QUANTITY".PadRight(15))

For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    sb.AppendLine(lvi.SubItems(0).Text.PadRight(15) & lvi.SubItems(1).Text.PadRight(15) & lvi.SubItems(2).Text.PadRight(15))
Next

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("order_receipt.txt", sb.ToString())

Process.Start("order_receipt.txt")
```

This is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

This is an example of the padding going wrong. Here I have used **10** to pad with:

[image]